# Can/should I automatically report network break-in attempts?

Tags: attacks, ssh, vulnerability, incident-response, blacklist

For the last 15 years I've been using [SpamCop](http://spamcop.net/) to report the spam I receive.  I do this because

- it sometimes results in spammers and the third-party machines they compromise getting shut down, at least temporarily (as evidenced by the occasional responses I get from ISPs thanking me for my reports and confirming that they've terminated access);
- it helps build real-time blackhole lists that others can use to help filter spam; and
- it requires almost no effort on my part, since my reporting workflow is largely automated.

If there's one type of network traffic I get even more of than spam, it's password-guessing attempts on my SSH servers.  Is there some SpamCop-like service I can or should be using to report attempts to break into my machines via SSH or other network services?

I already know about and employ various defences against such break-in attempts, but that's not what this question is about.  What I'm asking is

- whether at least some ISPs want to be informed when their networks are being abused for break-in attempts,
- whether there are any centralized IP blocklists that people can use to help filter maliciously employed IPs from incoming network connections, and
- whether there is some software or online service that allows me to automatically submit reports for either or both of the above two purposes.

Comment: similar to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/reporting-an-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered one service that purports to collect reports of attempted break-ins to SSH, mail, web, FTP, and other servers, and to forward these on to the listed abuse contacts for the originating networks.  The service in question is [www.BlockList.de](https://www.blocklist.de), which bills itself as a sort of SpamCop for other-than-spam network abuse:

> [www.blocklist.de](http://www.blocklist.de) is a free and voluntary service provided by a Fraud/Abuse-specialist, whose servers are often attacked via SSH-, Mail-Login-, FTP-, Webserver- and other services.
> The mission is to report any and all attacks to the respective abuse departments of the infected PCs/servers, to ensure that the responsible provider can inform their customer about the infection and disable the attacker.
>
> We report more than 70,000 attacks every 12 hours in real time using Whois (abuse-mailbox, abuse@, security@, email, remarks), the Ripe-Abuse-Finder, and the contact-database from abusix.com so we may find the abuse-address assigned to the offending host. Our reports are based on X-Arf (Network Abuse Reporting 2.0), so the abuse-department of the provider for the attacking host may parse our reports automatically.
>
> blocklist is comparable with spamcop.net for attacks of any nature, with an exception for spam.

I have no experience with using this service, though according to its own documentation it seems to do exactly what I had in mind, and moreover seems to integrate well with fail2ban.